# finding the largest possible divisor

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code in C, wherein I am declaring two variables A,B and A>=B,

Given two integers A and B, find the largest number ≤A which is completely divisible by B. Print the largest integer less than or equal to A which is completely divisible by B, in a separate line.

I tried to solve, but the solution isn't getting accepted with a runtime error. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long A, B, flag = 1;
    scanf("%lli", &A);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%lli", &B);
    for(int i = 1; i <= A; i++)
    {
        while(B > 0)
        {
            if(i % B == 0)
                flag = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%lli\n", flag);
    return 0;
}
```

So then I went to with another approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long A, B, n;
    scanf("%lli", &A);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%lli", &B);
    if(A >= 1 && B >= 1 && A >= B)
    {
        n = A % B;
        if(A % B == 0)
            printf("%lli\n", A);
        else
            printf("%lli\n", A - n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But here it isn't accepting the code at all showing wrong answer.

I don't know, where I am making an error , though these programs are running on VS CODE.

Comment: Why are you using scanf to read parameters?  It would be much more appropriate to use `strtoll(argv[i], NULL, 10);`

Comment: Do you mean **G**reatest **C**ommon **D**ivisor of two numbers ([GCD](https://www.google.com/search?q=greatest+common+divisor+C))?

Comment: In the first program why is `i` not a `long long`?

Comment: This gives an impression of being rephrased by you but based on a misunderstanding of what the goal actually is. If there is an original description (e.g. an assignment or challenge) please quote that directly, fully, verbatim and as text here.

Comment: @Yunnosch : Given two integers A and B, find the largest number ≤A which is completely divisible by B. Print the largest integer less than or equal to A which is completely divisible by B, in a separate line.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the input you use, the output or error message you get and the expected output. Please add all clarification or requested information to the question, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: @pmg I tried putting 'i' as ' long long'  , but still its showing runtime error

Comment: @AviralMishra Please copy&paste the runtime error to the question.

Comment: `while (B > 0) { /* code that does not change B */ }` is an infinite loop

Comment: The question seems unclear to me, because the largest number completly divisible by B, smaller or equal A (which is how I understand the goal), is `A-(A%B)`, isn't it? Please explain what I misunderstood.

Comment: My guess : `if(A >= 1 && B >= 1 && A >= B)` discards negative integers, and the definition of the expected output does not state that the integers should be only positive ones.

Comment: @Yunnosch , Let me try with an example, Supposing if I take A= 15 and B= 4 then since A is not divisible completely by B the output  has be 12, that is the nearest divisor ( smaller that A)  and instead if A would have been 16, then the output will be 16 itself.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Zilog80 sorry, my bad. Actually, constraint provided was , 1<=B<=A<=10^9.

Comment: Then your _"another approach"_ seems right. You can replace the whole `if(A % B == 0) {}` with only `printf("%lli\n", A - n);` for readability. I guess then that the trouble is the output format. The _"in a separate line"_ is probably the key, is there any other constraint relative to output format ?

Comment: As A and B should be less than 10^9, the trouble can also come from the C compiler to which your code is submitted. `long long` is supported till C99, if your target compiler is below that, you should stick with simples `int` instead of `long long`.

Comment: @Zilog80 Yes right, Thanks, I found that bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** The runtime error may result from your use of incompatible types:

```c
    long long A, B, flag = 1;
    ....
    for(int i = 1; i <= A; i++)
```

The `long long` type of `A` may well have a larger range than `int` type of `i`. If so, your loop variable `i` may never reach the value given in `A`. And you can't know what happens when the loop reaches `i==INT_MAX`. Most probably `i` will wrap over to a big negative value, which is still less than `A`, and the loop will iterate forever – hence a time limit is hit and the program gets aborted.

This won't happen if input values are less than `INT_MAX`, which apparently is the case. (However, the constraints should be given in a question, not in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206309/finding-the-largest-possible-divisor/68206586?noredirect=1#comment120546395_68206309) below it.)

**2.** The main problem is an infinite loop `while(B > 0) {...}` as pointed out by @pmg in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206309/finding-the-largest-possible-divisor/68206586?noredirect=1#comment120545815_68206309). The loop body doesn't modify `B`, hence the loop condition, once verified, stays true forever.

**3.** Another source of problem with automatic verification may be the output format, as @Zilog80 points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206309/finding-the-largest-possible-divisor/68206586?noredirect=1#comment120546541_68206309). Remove unnecessary `printf("\n");` instruction from your code.

**4.** BTW, loops are not necessary here at all. The integer division gives a result truncated, so the largest multiple of `B` not greater than `A` (both positive) is simply:

```
    A / B * B
```

Comment: That is what I thought (though I used a different operator for the same idea....). Either the two of us hugely misunderstood something - or the goal and OPs attempts are some orders of magnitude apart....

Comment: Please can you elaborate this a bit.

Comment: I was applauding and agreeing with your answer, not pointing out any shortcoming. It nevertheless got even better now. Wish I could upvote again. (Please stay with NOT giving the full code....)

Comment: Aviral Mishra. It was short, but it already is elaborate now. What do you need? Would you like a complete program which, handed in, runs and gets full marks? That would not help you, because your goal cannot be to get this solved but should be to learn how to solve this. And for that, all info is in this very good answer.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes Thanks, I got that. You pointed out that right. But just for the point 3, the compiler is demanding the inputs in 2 different lines, that's why I wrote that printf ("\n")

Comment: Aviral Mishra. There are many questions and answers concerning input. Please do not mix that topic into this question. Ask a new question if that is now your remaining problem.

Comment: @AviralMishra With your current input code the user is required to press the Return key at least once. The output of `'\n'` does not enforce a newline betwenn the two numbers. Instead of entering the numbers in separate lines, the user could as well enter e.g. `123 45` in one line and press the Return key. In any case the Return key after the second number will in make the output appear on a new line. If you have specific requirements for the input, write a new question as already suggested in [Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch)'s comment.

Comment: @Bodo There needn't be any user and the input stream needn't even be attached to any console. It may be piped from another process or from a file. So there is no 'Return presses' and no interleaving of input echo with output. Apparently OP hasn't grasped the idea of streams yet and doesn't realize the 'lines' visible at their console are not the same the judging software will see.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need of loop in this question. This has a very simple logic. Just you need to change your approach.

See this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long A, B;
    scanf("%lld", &A);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%lld \n", &B);
    
    printf("%lld",(A - (A % B) ));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the original algorithm.
See [CiaPan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733637/ciapan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68206586/10622916) for a much easier solution that doesn't need to try all numbers in a loop.

---

Instead of the endless loop `while(B > 0) { ... }` use `if(B > 0)` outside the `for` loop.

If you want to be able to handle big numbers by using the type `long long` for variables `A` and `B` you should use the same type for the loop variable `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long A, B, flag = 1;
    scanf("%lli", &A);
//    printf("\n");
    scanf("%lli", &B);
    if(B > 0)
    {
        for(long long i = 1; i <= A; i++)
        {
            if(i % B == 0)
                flag = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%lli\n", flag);
    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm can be improved in two ways.

- A number that is divisable by `B` must be greater than or equal to `B`, so you don't need to check smaller numbers.
- To find the largest number you can start from `A` and count down to `B` or until you found a divisable number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long A, B, flag = 0;
    scanf("%lli", &A);
//    printf("\n");
    scanf("%lli", &B);
    if(B > 0)
    {
        for(long long i = A; (i >= B) && (flag == 0); i--)
        {
            if(i % B == 0)
                flag = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%lli\n", flag);
    return 0;
}
```